# W3C validation error for input type=date

Tags: html, w3c-validation

```
<input type="date" max="1995-12-31" class="form-control" id="dob"/>
```

When I try to validate with W3C I got error for this line:

> The date input type is not supported in all browsers. Please be sure
>   to test, and consider using a polyfill.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. That message is just a warning message, not an error. And the reason we have the HTML checker emit that warning is, `input type=date` isn’t supported in desktop Safari or Internet Explorer, nor in versions of Firefox before Firefox 57, nor on Android before Android 4.4.

For the exact details about browser support, see https://caniuse.com/#search=date

So that warning’s purpose is to give you a heads-up that your document has a feature that doesn’t work as specified for users of Internet Explorer, Safari, and older versions of Firefox and Android.

That’s why the warning specifically mentions that you consider using a polyfill—in order to ensure that the feature works for all your users as expected.

To make `input type=date` work in all browsers, you can choose among many available polyfills:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodep-date-input-polyfill
- https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dateinput-polyfill
- https://github.com/liorwohl/html5-simple-date-input-polyfill
- https://github.com/dxw/date-polyfill
- https://github.com/jonstipe/date-polyfill

Comment: Thank you for your response but how to make it work in all browser

Comment: To make it work in all browsers, you can use a polyfill. I’ve updated the answer to add a list of some of the polyfills available

Comment: If you use the polyfill the warning goes away?

Comment: First three links have no deps. Others require jQuery. Link 1 is a fork of link 3. Awesome list!